# How to validate a form and uploaded file seperate in the same method

Tags: php, laravel, file, validation, upload

I'm trying to understand uploading files in laravel for a project I'm working on.
Sadly I failed when trying to achieve what I had in mind.

When a form is submitted you get to a site where all your inputs are displayed so you can check them again. So the form data has already been validated to this point.
On this site is also an input button to upload a file.

This means that both will go through the same controller method to be displayed after the validation is successful.

Problem here is that, even though the validation of the form works perfectly, I don't know how to validate the file.
Here you can see the store-method:

```
public function store(ValidateFormData $request, ValidateUploadedFile $requestFile, $param = '')
{
   $validated = $request->validated();
   $formData = $request->all();

   if ($requestFile->hasFile('file')) {
     $file = $requestFile->file('file');
     // call to $requestFile/validate the uploaded file
   }

   return view('/validation', compact('formData'));
}
```

**EDIT**

I just need the file to be a pdf/postscript file and successfully uploaded.
This is the rule I have in ValidateUploadedFile:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'datei' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf,ps',
  ];
}
```

I really hope someone can help me.
Please do not link any of the Laravel documentation, believe me, I've seen way to many sites about this topic but still don't quite get it.

Comment: What kind of file validation do you need to do? You're dependency injecting multiple requests, maybe one is enough? This might help you with eliminating unexpected behaviour in the future.

Comment: @DeesOomens But I need these two validations at different times, I can't put them both in one Request class..

Comment: Okay. So what file validation do you need? Laravel has multiple file validation rules, as you can read in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#available-validation-rules). So if you tell use what it is that you need to validate, we can help you find an answer.